# R Plotly: add loess line on subset

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly, loess

I am trying to fit a loess line (or lineair model) of the entire dataframe on a subset of the dataframe using plotly.

```
model_LV2F<- loess(p_LV2F ~schoolweging, data = df)
plot_ly(df_subset) %>% 
  add_markers(x=~schoolweging, y=~p_LV2F, marker=list(color="red", opacity=3/10), name="2F") %>%
  add_lines(x=~schoolweging, y=~model_LV2F$fitted, line=list(color="red"))
```

I get the error "Tibble columns must have compatible sizes.", because the model is based on 6000 observations, while the subsetted dataframe contains only 23 observations.

How can I add a pre-calculated reference line from another dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure it's not the most R-solution, but I managed to get it done.
I wrote a function to extract all x and y pairs of the fitted line, and retained only the unique values.
After that, i can join those values on my subsetted dataframe.

```
loess_ref <- function(...) {
  mdl <- loess(...)
  x <- mdl$x[, ]
  y <- mdl$fitted
  mdl_df <- data.frame(x, y) %>% drop_na() %>% unique()
}

loess_LV2F <- loess_ref(p_LV2F ~ schoolweging, data = df)

df_subset %>%
  left_join(loess_LV2F, by = c("schoolweging" = "x")) %>%
  plot_ly() %>%
  add_markers(
    x =  ~ schoolweging,
    y =  ~ p_LV2F,
    marker = list(color = "red", opacity = 3 / 10),
    name = "2F"
  ) %>%
  add_lines(
    x =  ~ schoolweging,
    y =  ~ model_LV2F$fitted,
    line = list(color = "red")
  )
```